# Game of Nim Sum Challenge Problem

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

Suppose in the game of Nim there are 72 chips in the first pile, 60 chips in the second pile, and 100 chips in the third pile and it is your turn to play. How would you play?

Following the below formula for base two, how can I go about solving?
[image]

Comment: First step: write out $72, 60,$ and $100$ in binary. Can you do that?

Comment: Yes I can do that:

Comment: OK, then do it here please...

Comment: 72 = 1001000, 60= 111100, 100= 1100100

Comment: OK, second step is to compute the Nim sum $1001000_2\oplus 111100_2\oplus 1100100_2$. If you are a programmer, $\oplus$ is just the XOR operation. Can you do that?

Comment: Also, please put `@TonyK` in your comment, so that I get notified.

Answer (score 2):

$72\oplus 60 \oplus 100 = 16$ as a decent binary calculator will tell you.
Or note that $$\begin{align} 72 &= 64+8= & 2^6 + 2^3 \\
100 &= 64 + 32 + 4 = & 2^6 + 2^5 + 2^2 \\
60 &= 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 = & 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^2 \\
\end{align}$$

and note that only $2^4$ is not cancelled by the same power in another sum, while all other $2^i$ are.

As $60\oplus 16 =44$ we just need to reduce the $60$ pile to a $44$ pile (the only pile here that contains the power $2^4$) to give the opponent a value of $44 \oplus 72 \oplus 100 = 0$ making him/her lose.

Comment: How do I reduce 60 to a 44 pile based on the power of 2's you broke down?

Comment: @MathStudent2 you need to compensate the $16$ (reduce the sum from $16$ to $0$) to win and $60$ has the only $16$ in its binary expansion. So remove $16$ from the 60 pile, and leave $44$ in that pile. After that move the nim-sum of the numbers (their xor) is $0$ and the one whose turn it is (your opponent) loses.

Comment: Thank you Henno. Would you be able to review my other problem I posted on Wythoffs game?